# Can't retrieve value of JSON Object attr after json_encode in PHP

Tags: php, json, object, encode

I'm not able to get the value of the `image` attribute in this (apparently valid) JSON object:

```
echo var_dump($result);

array(1) {
  ["images"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["src"]=>
      string(112) "http://staticf5a.diaadia.info/sites/default/files/styles/landscape_310_155/public/nota_periodistica/taxis_13.jpg"
    }
  }
}

$jsonResult = json_encode($result); //result is an array of arrays
echo $jsonResult;

{"images":[{"src":"http:\/\/staticf5a.diaadia.info\/sites\/default\/files\/styles\/landscape_310_155\/public\/nota_periodistica\/taxis_13.jpg"}]}

echo $jsonResult->images; //show nothing
```

This snippet was working few days ago, and logs (`ini_set('display_errors', '0');`) don't show anything related.

Comment: And what's happening now?

Comment: so, you encode it, and try to get property from a string, or did i understood faulty?

Comment: I have a condition based on $jsonResult 
`$jsonResult->images != null` should be true in this case, but goes false.

Comment: For JSON Object try `->{'images'}`.

Comment: json_encode returns a string, which you then can json_decode, to get an object, which does have an images element

Comment: yes, @Elentriel. I encoded some array, return a valid JSON but I cant get property.

Comment: I just change my condition, now check on array if result["images] is null or not.
Thanks everybody

Comment: I think you need a better understanding of what JSON is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON and what `json_encode` returns: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php . There is no such thing as a "JSON object" in PHP.

Comment: You right, I was confused. So I used array itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After encoding, `$jsonResult` is just a string and you won't be able to access any elements of encoded JSON without decoding it first.

Have a look at PHP's ``json_decode'' function: http://php.net/manual/pl/function.json-decode.php

It will convert the JSON back to associative array or object.

Anyway, I have no idea why you encode the associative array as JSON and try to access `images` there instead of just taking it from the array itself.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get property from a string here. `json_encode()` returns the json representation of an object as a string. That string you can turn into an actuall object with `json_decode()`